# RWM operation using DashMap

Tags: rust

I would like to atomically do the following with a DashMap:

1. Check if a key is present
2. If key is not, present init and insert a value for the key.
3. Update the value

A trivial example would be, say maintaining sequence numbers for a bunch of buckets, so `DashMap<Bucket, u64>` where the initial sequence number is random. With e.g. Java's ConcurrentHashMap, I could do something like:

```
map.compute(key, (_, value) -> value == null ? sample_initial() : value + 1);
```

The only way to do this that is race free that I can find with DashMap is to do:

```
let shard_ind = map.determine_map(key);
let locked = map.shards_mut()[shard_ind].get_mut();
let value = if !locked.contains_key(key) {
    let initial = sample_initial();
    locked.insert(key.clone(), initial);
    initial
} else {
    let value = locked.get_key_value_mut(key).unwrap().1.get_mut();
    *value += 1;
    *value
}
```

However, this seems incredibly complex for such a simple operation. Another issue is that the whole point with DashMap is to be able to share it in an Arc across threads, because it relies on interior mutability. Unfortunately, `shards_mut()` takes `&mut self`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can use [entry API](https://docs.rs/dashmap/5.5.3/dashmap/struct.DashMap.html#method.entry) to do this.

Comment: entry.and_modify(...).or_insert(initial) seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, entry API is really nice. Note that this not something specific to `DashMap`. You have access to it in [standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) as well.